# Nautilus sleeping refuses to launch after upgrade to 22.10

Tags: nautilus, 22.10

After upgrading to Kinetic Kudu, whenever I launch nautilus (using terminal or otherwise), nothing happens, and the app won't launch.

In System Monitor, its status is "Sleeping".

Comment: Could you launch nautilus in the terminal? perhaps it will log something to console

Comment: Same fore me when launching from activities. Once I kill the process, I can start nautilus from the terminal. Closing it leaves the terminal hanging for a while. Once it returns to prompt, I can start nautilus successfully from there again.